# nuxt - how do i access query string on the server

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

`/trips?date=2020-08-24&origin=6&destination=8` given the prior path, i am able to access query string values/object when navigating, but unable to access it when directly requesting the url, or on reloading the page.

```
async asyncData ({ query }) {
    if (process.server) {
      console.log(query)
    } else {
      console.log(query)
    }
}
```

on the server, `{ query }` is logged as an empty object `{}`, however on the client `{date: "2020-08-24", origin: "6", destination: "8"}`.

I tried in `asyncData` and in `middleware`, same result, i have set `watchQuery` property to true, it has been very helpful to update the component whenever the query string is changed. but irrelevant to the server.

I was trying to avoid the work around of joining mutliple parameters together like `/trips/2020-08-24-6-8`. Now im starting to think it's due to a deficiency in my understanding of nuxt and the server side rendering concept.

Comment: I can get the query correctly on the client and server in my project. My nuxt version is 2.8.1

Comment: i tested on codesandbox.io, and it actually worked. im creating new nuxt app now. thanks for feedback

Comment: perhaps it has to do with being static app. i have nuxt.config.js
  mode: 'universal',
  target: 'static',
is yours static?

Comment: i think this is related https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/7627

Comment: my mode is `universal` and target is `server` default